# Sorting Number Compiler Error

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to sorting a list of numbers using radixsort. But ran into a compiler
problem that I cannot solve after multiple tries.

I have two pointers one at the back of the list and the other in front. 
base is the the number of buckets I am using for radixsort.

```
struct listnode **front,**back;
front =  malloc(sizeof(*front) * base);
back =   malloc(sizeof(*back) * base);
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
invalid conversion from void* to listnode**[-fpermissive]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Comment: It looks like you are using C++, but tagged it as C. Which language are you using?

Comment: @Marlon I am using C under g++ in cmd

Comment: Comment deleted. (Oops, now this one's an orphan.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using a C++ compiler to compile your C program.  Either don't do that, or add a typecast to the return value of the `malloc()` calls.

Comment: I using g++ under windows. how would I do the typecast for malloc?

Comment: In your case, `front = (listnode **)malloc(sizeof....)`.  But why would you want to use a C++ compiler?

Comment: I have to have my program working through gcc or g++ compiler. I tried your suggestions and it works. Thanks.

Comment: So if it's a C program, why aren't you using `gcc`?

Comment: I thought that gcc and g++ compiler were the same for c++ and c programs.

Comment: No - C++ and C are different languages.  g++ is a C++ compiler and gcc is a C compiler.

Comment: "gcc" stands for the "gnu compiler collection" these days, and it includes separate C and C++ compilers.  The front end normally chooses which language to compile based on the name of your file: "foo.c" means C code while "foo.c++" and "foo.cxx" (among others) mean C++ code.  The problem is that "foo.C" *also* means C++.  Name the file with lowercase, or use the "-x" switch to force language choice, to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine as a C program. Save the file with a .c extension an then compile it...

Still, if you want to compile it as a C++ program, you need to do a cast as

```
  struct listnode **front,**back;
    front =  static_cast<listnode**> (malloc(sizeof(*front) * base));
    back =   static_cast<listnode**> (malloc(sizeof(*back) * base));
```

The reason is that C++ is a strongly typed language and does not allow the type of conversions between pointers like C does. You have to explicitly specify such a cast in C++. Implicit casts between pointers is a source of hard find bugs and thus not supported in C++.